# Getting status of a different branch in git

Tags: git, git-status

I have a `git` repository that contains two branches, `master` and `experiments`. The latter contains experiments that do not belong in branch `master`, but may later be merged so I'd like to keep it up to date with changes made to master.

To do so, I run `git fetch` (from any branch), then have to checkout to `master` to run `git status` (and possibly `git whatchanged`) and know whether I need/want to update `master` from the remote (and merge it to `experiments`).

Did I miss a `git` command/option to get the status of `master` (ie, whether or not `fetch` downloaded commits to `master` that need to be merged, and what commits were downloaded) without having to change branch first?

Comment: you can use [git scripts](https://github.com/jwiegley/git-scripts) for getting status of branch

Comment: Git has no concept of "status of a branch".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git status` gives you the status of your working tree and not a single branch.

If you want to see whether `master` is ahead of `experiments`, you can do a diff between the two branches or do a log from one of them to see if it covers the other.

Comment: Thanks, I settled for `git log ..origin/master`.